# Is there any Android phone that can wake up for alarms even when the battery has died?

Tags: battery, alarm

My old Nokia N95 used to wake up for alarms even when the battery had died.

Is there any current Android smartphone that can do this?

Comment: You mean when it had shut down due to low battery level? Unless it had a little button battery or something for that purpose.  Either way, I don't know of any Android phones that wake up when they're off, nevermind dead.

Comment: Yes, shut down due to low battery level.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/whats-the-reason-that-the-alarm-clock-isnt-working-when-the-phone-is-turned-off

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate question, but it is closely related. There does not appear to be any Android phones out there that have reserve power for things like alarms. When your phone is off, it is *off*. This is probably why they offer desk docks where the phone goes into "clock" mode when docked. (I have one for my Droid and I love it. It's my secondary alarm clock.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a NO.

Star this issue if you're interested in Google adding the necessary framework for a hardware alarm: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1942