# Alarm which could Ring even when Device is Off

Tags: applications, rom, alarm, device-firmware

Android smartphones are smarter than traditional mobile phones in all aspects, but I am unable to find this smartness in one aspect: In those classic mobile phones, there was an option to ring the alarm even when device was off. The device was turned on temporarily to ring alarm, then turned off.

How to do this in an Android device? I know, its not possible by app unless supported by firmware. So, I am asking for ROM hacks etc.

Please, don't answer if its "You Can't" or "Not Possible" etc..

Comment: Some related discussion: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/does-the-alarm-work-when-my-phone-is-turned-off

Comment: Also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/whats-the-reason-that-the-alarm-clock-isnt-working-when-the-phone-is-turned-of

Comment: Does your phone support Scheduled Power ON or OFF?

Answer (score 5):

[NoMoarPowah!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.nomoarpowah) ([alternative link](https://root-nomoarpowah-pro.en.aptoide.com/app)) can boot the phone up based on your scheduled alarms, in time for them to ring.  It only works on certain Samsung devices.

Comment: Brave answer, but.. The app works only when device is charging (as it replaces battery status firmware program).

Comment: @SachinShekhar I'm assuming that running something similar while the phone is not charging would require a hardware change, but perhaps that's incorrect.  You're essentially looking for a low-power micro-OS to be running as long as the battery is not dead ... that may be nigh-impossible as well without manufacturer support, since [the bootloaders aren't open-source](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6156/1465) and thus difficult to work with.  If you're shutting the phone off to save battery you may want to consider other battery-saving methods.

Comment: BTW, it can be done without involving bootloaders and manufacturers, as I think. Micro-OS type instance can be attached with recovery. And, shut down function can be replaced with "reboot to recovery". Its just one idea..

Comment: @SachinShekhar That's quite an interesting idea, actually!

Comment: Just FYI, the app is not available on the Play Store anymore.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT., added an Aptoide link as well.  (The Play link still works for me, presumably because one of my devices still has it installed.)