# Schedule Auto Shutdown on Android

Tags: automation, shutdown

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and was wondering if it's possible (like on Blackberry) to setup a schedule for automatic device shutdown.

For example, on my previous phone, I could indicate for the phone to auto shutdown at 12AM and auto turn on at 7AM.

Is it possible on Android without download third-party app?

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible in general. There may be exceptions though: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/alarm-which-could-ring-even-when-device-is-off?lq=1

Comment: Well, let's say it's only half possible: shutdown is easily accomplished via Tasker. For the "turn on" part you need an external tool pressing the button, sorry...

Comment: When the phone is off, it's **off**. There's no way to wake it up (short of the power button) because it's not asleep. It's for this reason that alarms don't work when the phone is off, which has caused some consternation [1](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/alarm-which-could-ring-even-when-device-is-off) [2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/does-the-alarm-work-when-my-phone-is-turned-off) [3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/whats-the-reason-that-the-alarm-clock-isnt-working-when-the-phone-is-turned-of) to people used to dumber phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natively, there is no way to schedule shutdowns and boot ups of the Android system. If you do decide to root there are applications in the Play store that can shedule a shutdown (you may even be able to make your own busybox script instead). However booting up will never be possible the way Android handles shut downs because when Android shuts down, it is not running.And so, there is nothing in memory to initiate any sort of startup process.

Answer (score 0):

Flo files uploaded at following address one of the file consists of scheduled power off , you need rooted phone and Automate app from play store

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-automate-t2870633/post80126909#post80126909

Answer (score -1):

I have Samsung Galaxy Pro Duos (Ginger Bread) in which there is no feature like this, but my wife have Xolo A700(ICS OS) in which there is simmilar kind of feature by which phone can be switch off and on in scheduled time. I found Xolo Phones are more value for money in compare to Samsung. BTW 'Phone Schedule' Apps available in Play Store which can turn on/off Airplane mode as per the Schedule time given. but not found something which can Turn off or On completely