# How to schedule power on & off on a tablet?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tablet, automation, alarm

I have an Asus TF303CL with KitKat.
I'd like to use it as my alarm clock, but it seems that the alarm cannot sound if the tablet is turned off during the night.

On my previous android smartphone (a chinese phone with gingerbread) I could simply go to settings and set the time at which the phone would turn off and the time at which the phone would turn on in the morning, so my phone was *completely turned off* during the night (it was *not* in airplane mode, it was *turned off*), turned on 5 minutes before the alarm and the alarm could sound.

How can I achieve the same effect with this tablet?
I've already checked the settings but I cannot find any entry similar to what I had on the old phone.

I **know** it's possible, since I've been able to do that for 2 years with a basic chinese smartphone; surely this brand new tablet can do everything that old phone could do. Maybe rooting the device is required for such a functionality?

Comment: Just because one phone had the option to do that, doesn't mean every device is made that way!  This isn't a common feature on most phones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the alarm work when my phone is turned off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/does-the-alarm-work-when-my-phone-is-turned-off)

Comment: @eldarerathis It's not a duplicate of that question. If you read my question you'll realize I know perfectly well that the alarm application can't, by itself, work if the phone/tablet is off. That's exactly why I'm asking how to automatically schedule on & off, so that the tablet can be turned on at the right time for the alarm to sound. And this, I stress, **is** possible. A valid answer to this question should either 1) provide a means of doing this or 2) provide a means to determine whether a particular device support this feature or not.

Comment: I did read your question. You want the alarm to work even when the device is shut off. How you get from A to B does not seem material to the question, and if such a workaround existed then it would also be an entirely valid answer to the linked question. You have the exact same underlying goal. And, as an aside: no matter how much you "stress that it's possible", it doesn't mean that it actually is. Your older device supported this apparently, but that's totally irrelevant to your *current* device. It may work on both, but there is no guarantee that it will.

Comment: Alternatively, see [Alarm which could Ring even when Device is Off](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/alarm-which-could-ring-even-when-device-is-off), or even more discussion of the feasibility of this at [What's the reason that the alarm clock isn't working when the phone is turned off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/whats-the-reason-that-the-alarm-clock-isnt-working-when-the-phone-is-turned-of)