# If a Android device is turned off, does the alarm sound?

Tags: alarm

If a alarm is set and a Android device gets turned off (for whatever reason), does the alarm still sound?

I want to generically refer to Android (latest version if it makes any difference) and we are talking about stock Android

Comment: Wouldn't an experiment take less than a minute or two? Set an alarm for 1 minute into the future, turn off the phone and experience your answer.

Comment: Why do I have to have a Android device on hand? Why should it be running the latest version of Android?

Comment: See: [Does the alarm work when my phone is turned off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4206/16575) and [What's the reason that the alarm clock isn't working when the phone is turned off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4739/16575)

Comment: Read those already. I just wanted to confirm that it was not in Android.

Comment: This site is (obviously) entirely devoted to Android, so you can rest assured that those answers apply to Android.  Please don't ask questions you know are duplicates.

Comment: You misunderstood my statement. I wanted to confirm that it was not in the source code for the Android operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the phone and on the alarm app. Some offer this specific function in case your phone does not wake automatically. Some other offer a scheduled wake to turn your phone on just before your alarm has to ring.

Anyway, if you put your phone into airplane mode, it is much like turning it off: provided background apps are closed, all your phone is gonna do is wait for the alarm to ring. It will not send or receive data (for those who don't like waves near them all night when they sleep), and it is gonna leave your battery level near untouched.

Comment: Stock Android, latest version. True turn off, no sleep or anything else.

Comment: I said it depended on the phone, not on the ROM. Do you mean stock Android's alarm app? Also, I never said anything about sleep, I just mentioned airplane mode as an alternative to turning your phone off during the night. If you want to know in case of an accidental turn off, the first paragraph is my answer.

Comment: How can it depend on the physical phone? It has to be a software feature. This is a question, not geared towards alternative answers.

Comment: unfortunately, arplane mode cannot be scheduled. It would be a replacement for me otherwise.